# Getting a Group ID for Facebook private/secret group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build an app that will make an API call to the feed of a Facebook group. I would like for the ability to make this API call to secret or private groups. I understand that this requires the `user_groups` permission when doing this via API calls, and I understand that the `user_groups` permission is basically unobtainable right now.

I am totally willing for the user to manually go somewhere in Facebook to copy and paste this group ID from a secret/private group (much like you do in the URL of a public group). Is there any way at all to obtain the group ID of a private/secret group you are a part of without being the manager of that group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll never be able to pull a group's feed via the Graph API if you don't have a suitable access token. Even if the group id is known.

Also, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Quote:

> - the user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available in v2.4.

Comment: Ah, okay. Unfortunate that this API closed up so recently. Thanks.